# Problem getting certificate from let's encrypt using Traefik with docker

Tags: docker-compose, traefik

I've set up Traefik with Docker and a service behind it. The basic setup works. I can browse to port 80 using the domain name I'm redirected to https and then see "invalid certificate" - since the let's encrypt part is broken.

[ router ] <-:80/:443-> [linux/docker [Traefik:80/:443][Service:8080]]

Here is the entry in the log (edited domain.)

**Logs**:

> acme: Error -> One or more domains had a problem:\n[xyz.example.net] acme: error: 400 :: urn:ietf:params:acme:error:connection :: Fetching
>   http://xyz.example.net/.well-known/acme-challenge/eIAFZqaGMHMWaBjINjzk4m8PuWiYfuCHCTnSU9M:
>   Error getting validation data, url: \n"

The error message is accurate, I can not browse to that URL.  I have noticed that I can go to that URL using the internal IP `http://10.0.0.21/.well-known/acme-challenge/key` and Traefik responds with this in the log:

> traefik    | time="2019-05-28T21:20:52Z" level=error msg="Error getting challenge for token retrying in 542.914495ms"

I suspect the problem is the domain name redirect setup. My service is at xyz.example.net (and so is Traefik.) I suspect the problem is that Traefik is redirecting all traffic coming in on `xyz.example.net:80/:443` to the service, and not handling the `./well-known/acme-challenge` itself. Do I need to give the gateway itself a name? (E.g. `zzz.example.net` is Traefik and `xyz.example.net` is the service?)

How can I fix this?

My TOML file:

```
debug = false

logLevel = "ERROR" #DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR, FATAL, PANIC
InsecureSkipVerify = true
defaultEntryPoints = ["https", "http"]

[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
    [entryPoints.http.redirect]
    entryPoint = "https"
  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
    [entryPoints.https.tls]

[retry]

[docker]
endpoint = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
domain = "example.net"
watch = true
exposedbydefault = false

[acme]
email = "me@example.net"
storage = "acme.json"
entryPoint = "https"
onDemand = false 

onHostRule = true
[acme.httpChallenge]
entryPoint = "http"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that although the internal IP 192.xxx worked - the external IP did not.  Of course, I would say, this seems like a firewall problem - BUT - the firewall lets thru traffic just fine for the services that I was testing, so I was confused.

The solution? **port 80 was not being forwarded on the firewall**, 443 was. So when I tried testing with curl/browser I was typing in https://xyz.example.com - and that was working.